# How do I loose/exclude a footer when the user clicks a 'book now' button that opens a new window?

Tags: wordpress, web, mobile-website

My website is for booking appointments with a clinic. It therefore has a footer with a 'book now' button for users that opens a new window and takes you to an iframe in the 3rd party booking system (Get timely). Problem is the new window still displays my 'book now' button so the user gets confused between whether to click my button or the Get timely button to complete their booking once they ahve selected type, date and time of booking. Other than just removing the footer entierly and rearranging the website are there any fixes people have used before ?

I havent been able to try any solutions as of yet.

Comment: _"that opens a new window"_ - with a specific WordPress page from your site in it, presumably? Then it would probably be the easiest way to hide the irrelevant footer content on that page only, via a bit of custom CSS. The `body` element should contain a class relating to the specific post ID of that page, so you can use that to target descendants of body only on that particular page. Creating a new page _template_, that doesn't contain the footer, and gets assigned to this specific page only, would be another option.